# How do I merge several different files into a single file with custome file type using c#.net?

Tags: c#

I need to combine multiple files (video & music & text) into single file with a custom file type (for example: `*.abcd`) and custom file data structure , and the file should only be read by my program and my program should be able to separate parts of this file. How do this in `.net` & `c#`?

```
https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/ZWnh
```

Answer (score 4):

Like M463 rightly pointed out, you could use `System.IO.Compression` to compress those files together and encrypt them...although encryption is a completely different art and another headache.
A better option would be to have some metadata in, say, the first few bytes of the file and then store the files' bytes as raw bytes. This would avoid any person from figuring the contents by just looking at it in a text editor. Again, if you want to really protect your data, encryption is unavoidable. But a simple algorithm to begin with would be this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Compression
{
    public class ClassName
    {
        public static void Compress(string[] fileNames, string resultantFileName)
        {
            List<byte> bytesToWrite = new List<byte>();

            //add metadata about the number of files
            int filesLength = fileNames.Length;
            bytesToWrite.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(filesLength));

            List<byte[]> files = new List<byte[]>();
            foreach(string fileName in fileNames)
            {
                byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
                //add metadata about the size of each file
                bytesToWrite.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(bytes.Length));
                files.Add(bytes);
            }
            foreach(byte[] bytes in files)
            {
                //write the actual files itself
                bytesToWrite.AddRange(bytes);
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(resultantFileName, bytesToWrite.ToArray());
        }

        public static void Decompress(string fileName)
        {
            List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName));
            //this int represents the number of files in the byte array
            int filesLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes.ToArray(), 0);

            List<int> sizes = new List<int>();
            //get the size of each file
            for(int i = 0; i < filesLength; i++)
            {
                //the first 2 bytes represent the number of files
                //then each succeding int represents the size of each file
                int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes.ToArray(), 2 + i * 2);
                sizes.Add(size);
            }

            //now read all the files
            for(int i = 0; i < filesLength; i++)
            {
                int lastByteTillNow = 0;
                for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    lastByteTillNow += sizes[j];
                File.WriteAllBytes("file " + i, bytes.GetRange(2 + 2 * filesLength + lastByteTillNow, sizes[i]).ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now obviously this is not the best algorithm you've come across nor is it the most optimized snippet of code. After all, it is just what I could come up with in 10-15 mins. So I haven't even tested it yet. However, the point is, it gives you the idea doesn't it? I have limited the size of each file to the maximum length of an `Int32` (however, changing it to `Int64` a.k.a `long` wouldnt be much of a trouble). But it gives you an idea. You can even modify the snippet to load and write to and from the RAM via MemoryStreams (`Systtem.IO.MemorySteam` I think). But whatever, this should give you a start!

Comment: tanx john ...My program is similar to Microsoft Power Point .in pptx file you can put your texts and videos and then save the file with *.pptx format and load it anytime...

Comment: So did this help you? Then please accept this as the answer. It helps

Comment: I don't think you understand. This code might not work. This is just to give you the idea as to how the algorithm should work. Its to give you a headstart. It might not work out in your tests (however, if it doesn't please chat with me and let me know. I'd love to work on such an algorithm)

Comment: Try saving the file somewhere else. `F:\` is not accessible by the code. Perhaps try saving it in the root folder of the program and then you can try other folders

Comment: this works only for small files .. if files are large ( > 500 MB) , How do I use Memory Stream or other classes ?!?!

Comment: Indeed. That is because I am using `int` to store the size of files. Use `long` and that should give you better capacity. I even explained it in my answer. Didn't you read it?

Comment: yes tanx my friend . i read it but i want to use System.Io.MemoryStream .. how do i write bytes into RAM ? ..because my files are very large for example 500 MB / 700 MB

Comment: Use [Google](http://www.google.com) and read about the usage of `System.IO.MemoryStream`

Comment: Beyond a point, you must figure out things on your own my friend

Comment: If I pointed you in the right direction, please mark this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

How about an encrypted .zip-container containing your files? Handling of .zip-files is already available in the .NET-Framework, take a look at the `System.IO.Compression` namespace. Or you could use some third party library.

You could even force a different file extension by just renaming the file, if you really want to...

Comment: My program is similar to Microsoft Power Point .in pptx file you can put your text and video and then save the file with *.pptx format and load it anytime...